# click(function) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, animation, click

I tried to do some animation with click function button and left/right arrow keyboard, just a simple left-right sliding animation. At first those script works perfectly, til I edit here and there, but not these JS.

When I run it again, only the keyboard based animation works, the button click animation wont work anymore.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnright').click(function(){
        $('.project').animate({
         left: '-=150px',
        });
    });
    $('.btnleft').click(function(){
        $('.project').animate({
         left: '+=150px',
        });
    });
});
```

I do test the the click function with alert, but the alert wont work too.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnright').click(function(){
        alert('right');
        
    });
    $('.btnleft').click(function(){
        alert('left');
       
    });
});
```

And I already check if I used the wrong class, but now, it's just allright.

```html
<div class="btnright"><span class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</span></div>
    <div class="btnleft"><span class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</span></div>
```

Here are the keyboard animation script, this keyboard script works fine

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
    var x = event.keyCode;
    if (x == 37) {  // left
     $('.project').animate({
        left: '+=150px',
  });
 } else if (x == 39) {  // right
  $('.project').animate({
        left: '-=150px',
  });
 }
});
```

Maybe I'm missing something. I'll appreciate for ya'll help. Thx.

Comment: any console errors in your browser?

Comment: What if you change `$('.btnright').click(...)` to `$(document).on('click', '.btnright', ...)`?

Comment: [Looks like it should work just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/s8qdj37f/)

Comment: @Pointy Yes! and that's what frustate me a lot! :(

Comment: Note that my previous comment was a link to a jsfiddle where your code works.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, i do open that link and realize the scripts work, and no problem on the jsfiddle. But it's not working at all at my web.

Comment: @wrschneider 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btnright', function(){
        alert('right');
   });
    });


not working too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma from your options object. Also, you need to specify the duration for the animation. Also, `.project` would need to be absolutely or relatively positioned (instead of default of static) for `left` to have an effect. So:

```
$('.btnright').click(function(){
    $('.project').animate({
        left: '-=150px'
    }, 500);
});
```

With CSS:

```
.project {
  position: relative;
}
```

Instead of:

```
$('.btnright').click(function(){
    $('.project').animate({
        left: '-=150px',
    });
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQzazR

Comment: Are we testing this in IE7?

Comment: Commas in object literals weren't valid until ECMAScript 5. JSON specification still says trailing comma is illegal. It may not be an error in modern browsers, but still seems like best practice to avoid it.

Comment: I used fixed position before, and it works with the keyboard based animation. now i changed to relative, and no use at all, still the keyboard animation still work well on relative position :( frustrating ps: i use chrome

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why it's not working. Tested your top function and it [works fine](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQzazR). Can you also post all HTML/CSS? Maybe you haven't set the class names on your buttons properly?